# jQuery iosslider Page scroll

Tags: jquery, slider

I have an iosSlider v1.3.43 (06/17/2014) and I want to use the .iosSlider('prevPage') and .iosSlider('nextPage') methods but I can't manage to use the methods. I thought it was pretty simple but I can't get it to work.

I read the following post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23892753/jquery-iosslider-number-of-slides-per-scroll) and tried an onClick method but still nothing.

Below is my code :

```
jQuery('#homefeatured .newproducts .carousel').iosSlider({
    desktopClickDrag: true,
    snapToChildren: true,
    infiniteSlider: true,
    navNextSelector: '#homefeatured .new-arrow.next',
    navPrevSelector: '#homefeatured .new-arrow.prev',
    lastSlideOffset: 3,

    onFirstSlideComplete: function(){
        jQuery('#homefeatured .new-arrow.prev').addClass('disabled');
    },
    onLastSlideComplete: function(){
        jQuery('#homefeatured .new-arrow.next').addClass('disabled');
    },
    onSlideChange: function(){
        jQuery('#homefeatured .new-arrow.next').removeClass('disabled');
    },
});

jQuery('#homefeatured .new-arrow.prev').iosSlider('prevPage');
jQuery('#homefeatured .new-arrow.next').iosSlider('nextPage');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed event bind code.

See below..

```
jQuery('#homefeatured .new-arrow.prev').bind('click',function(){jQuery('#homefeatured .newproducts .carousel').iosSlider('prevPage')});
jQuery('#homefeatured .new-arrow.next').bind('click',function(){jQuery('#homefeatured .newproducts .carousel').iosSlider('nextPage')});
```

Good luck~

Comment: Please add some explanation and format your code. Explain why your code should work.